# Frameworks installed from cocoapods not working

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I've recently just started programming with swift, and I tried to use cocoapods to use Firebase. The first time I created a project and did all the cocoapod installation for Firebase, it worked. However, any other project I make with the Firebase installation will result in a missing module.

[image]

I also don't know what the white box next to Pods_FirebaseTest.framework is. On the app that worked, it showed the orange box like the ones at the bottom that says Firebase.framework and Pods_FirebaseTest.framework.

I've tried to move the frameworks from the bottom into the Build Phase->Link binary with Libraries, but it still displays that white box.

The image shown is a brand new project that I created specifically to test Firebase. It is essentially a completely blank project that you would get out directly from going to File->New->Project->Single-View Application. To install Firebase, I used the iOS Quickstart on Firebase's page [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html)

Comment: please show your podfile too